# c++ - cannot use overloaded operator defined before in template class member function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I defined a `Point<T, Size>` template class, which has a `std::array` as its member variable. I overload `[]` operator to conveniently access the array, however, I found that in some following member functions I can't use `[]` operator and some others otherwise.

I was thinking if this is a template-class-related issue?

Note: `Vector` is also a template class similar to `Point` and I think its definition is not related to the error. I'll post its code here if further needed.

```
template<typename T, unsigned Size>
    class Point {
    private:
        std::array<T, Size> _p;
    public:
        static const unsigned size = Size;

        inline T &operator[](unsigned i) { return _p[i]; }

        inline Point operator+(const Point &other) {
            Point ret;
            for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
                ret._p[i] = _p[i] + other[i]; // OK to directly access _p with [] operator
            }
            return ret;
        }

        inline Vector<T, Size> operator-(const Point &other) {
            Vector<T, Size> ret;
            for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++) ret[i] = _p[i] - other._p[i]; // compiler error if use other[i] directly
            return ret;
        }
    };
```

The only difference between the two commented functions, I think, is the return type. Can anyone tell me why the usage of `[]` operator is different?

```
error C2678: binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Point<float,3>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @StephenNewell Added to question description.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. The error should be reproducible, i.e. the code should include `Vector` declaration and `Point` instantiation.

Comment: FWIW if your class makes sense to have it's elements accesed directory through `operator[]` then it may make more sense to inherit from `std::array` than to encapsulate a `std::array` and forward methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `operator []` isn't available for `const` `Point`s.  Usually, when providing `operator []` you want to provide it in pairs:

```
inline T &operator[](unsigned i) { return _p[i]; }
inline T const &operator[](unsigned i) const { return _p[i]; }
```

As to why this is working in your `operator +` member function, you're probably never using it.

Comment: Both methods in OP code are not compiled. OP does not use `operator+` and thinks it is working. Thus I requested [mcve] and object instantiation in my comment to the question.

Comment: Good catch, @S.M..  The error was enough to figure out the `const` issue, but never occurred to me `operator +` wasn't being called.